# When is ActiveStorage::IntegrityError raised?

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My app (locally) raises `ActiveStorage::IntegrityError` error, whenever it tries to attach a file. How can I get out of this error?

I have only one `has_one_attached` and I don't know how that error gets in the way.

```ruby
# model
has_one_attached :it_file
Tempfile.open do |temp_file|
  # ...
  it_file.attach(io: temp_file, filename: 'filename.csv', content_type: 'text/csv')
end

# storage.yml
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

EDIT: it can be related with deleting `storage/` directory (it happened after I deleted that) or it can be because it's happening in a job (the full error was `Error performing ActivityJob (Job ID: .. ) from Async( .. ) in .. ms: ActiveStorage::IntegrityError (ActiveStorage::IntegrityError)`

And this does not add files to `storage/` folder but it's generating folders under it when I tried to attach them.

Comment: It was `Tempfile`. when I tried `temp_file.rewind` there, no more errors.

Comment: My colleague is getting same problem on his Docker environment. All other colleagues don't have this issue. [ActiveStorage::IntegrityError](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/ActiveStorage/IntegrityError) is raised when there is corruption of file revived (checksum don't match file revived) ....I'm still debugging this in my environment why  this exactly happened, Just posting here some notes ;)

Comment: @equivalent8 any more thoughts on why this happened.  I've been working on this for a while.  My issue seems to have something to do with Docker as well.

Comment: @equivalent8 did you ever solved this? I hit exactly the same problem on a docker environment, and I'm the only one getting it.

Answer (score 29):

As mentioned in the comments, one reason this can happen is that the file object is at the end of the file, which was the problem in this case. It could be fixed here with `temp_file.rewind`.

Comment: Yup, that was it for me, too. Same also applies for normal File instances.

Answer (score 6):

Very weird. After update to rails 6.0 I must recalculate some checksums. Yes I used dokku,docker. It was fine before update.

```
# Disk service is in use for ActiveStorage
class ProjectImage < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :attachment
end

# update all checksums
ProjectImage.all.each do |image|
  blob = image.attachment.blob
  blob.update_column(:checksum, Digest::MD5.base64digest(File.read(blob.service.path_for(blob.key))))
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

This was happening to me not because of anything mentioned above.

In my case I was defining a test var using one dummy file, but I was attaching it to 2 different records.

```rb
let(:file) { File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'en.yml')) }
let(:data) { [file, file] }
```

The function in question received a list of ids and data and attaching the files to the records. This is a simplified version of the code

```rb
record_0.file.attach(
  io: data[0],
  filename: 'en.yml',
  content_type: 'application/x-yaml'
)
record_1.file.attach(
  io: data[1],
  filename: 'en.yml',
  content_type: 'application/x-yaml'
)
```

Once I defined 2 test vars, one for each record, using the same file I got it to work.

```rb
let(:file_0) { File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'en.yml')) }
let(:file_1) { File.open(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'en.yml')) }
let(:data) { [file_0, file_1] }
```

Comment: Just found this answer that I had forgotten about and it solved a similar issue. I was attaching the same file in 2 different specs and started getting this error. I thought that since they were different `it` blocks it would re open the file but it seems it doesn't. After defining the same file twice it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### Background

In my case I faced this error when I was trying to upgrade the rails config defaults.

I was activating configs from `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_1.rb` which was generated by `rails app:update` rake task.

### Cause

I activated this setting

```rb
Rails.application.config.active_storage.track_variants = true
```

which collided with our existing mechanism to handle variant generation. We are reading variants size/types from account-settings so its complicated.

#### Technical cause

As mentioned above, this is causes due to mismatch in `checksum` of the file and `checksum` stored in `blob` record in database.

```rb
      # activestorage-6.1.7.1/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb:37

      def verify_integrity_of(file, checksum:)
        unless Digest::MD5.file(file).base64digest == checksum
          raise ActiveStorage::IntegrityError
        end
      end
```

### Solution

- I commented it back
- To make sure its always inactive, I moved the setting to `config/initializers/active_storage.rb` like below

```rb
# Track Active Storage variants in the database.
# *Note*: Its Rails 6.1.0 feature and we have our own way of handling variants which also depends upon the
# thumbnail_sizes setting values and varies from account to account.
# so we are disabling it for now.
Rails.application.config.active_storage.track_variants = false
```

### Summary

- You may want to use this awesome feature so see workarounds.
- In your case, causes can be something else so look deeper.
- disabling this feature solves my issue.